# Run a git repository with R locally

Tags: r, git

I try to run locally this [repository](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Senti4SD)

I installed git but when I run this command:

```
sh requirements.sh
```

I receive this error:

> ```
> $ sh requirements.sh
> Java is installed
> which: no C:Program in (/c/Users/Username/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Username/bin:/c/Perl64/site/bin:/c/Perl64/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program
> ```
>
> Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin:/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files
>   (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common
>   Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files/Git
>   LFS:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2:/c/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin:/c/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/Rscript.exe:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program
>   Files/Docker Toolbox:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
>       which: no FilesRR-3.5.2binR in (/c/Users/Username/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Username/bin:/c/Perl64/site/bin:/c/Perl64/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin:/c/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files
>   (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program
>   Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common
>   Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files/Git
>   LFS:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2:/c/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin:/c/Program
>   Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/Rscript.exe:/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program
>   Files/Docker Toolbox:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
>       R is installed
>       Warning in install.packages(c("caret"), dependencies = c("Imports", "Depends"),  :
>         'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library"' is not writable
>       Error in install.packages(c("caret"), dependencies = c("Imports", "Depends"),  :
>         unable to install packages
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>         there is no package called 'caret'
>       Execution halted

Please is there any idea what should I fix in the paths?

> Edit
>   Running another command I receive this error:

```
MINGW64 /c/git/Senti4SD/ClassificationTask (master)
$ Rscript requirements.R
Warning in install.packages(c("caret"), dependencies = c("Imports", "Depends"),  :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages(c("caret"), dependencies = c("Imports", "Depends"),  :
  unable to install packages
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'caret'
Execution halted
```

Comment: @Gregor as I can see it accepts the sh command but when it comes the time to execute the r script with requirements there is a problem. I am not sure if there is any problem with R paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the command line couldn't find the "which" command, which is supplied with mingw.

If you installed Git for Windows, you should try looking for a installed program called "Git bash" and run your script from there.

You should be able to right click the folder and select "open git bash here", if you installed the Explorer extension.

**Edit**:
Its a problem related to install permission. Try running "Git bash" with Administrative privileges in Windows.

If the bash dont work, run "Rscript requirements.R" directly.

Comment: What is the output of "which R" ran from git bash?

Comment: It is /c/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/R